# Problem with grid when trying to use groupby in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

When trying to use GROUPBY I get an error saying a field 'date1' is not found on selected resource.

```
   var query = (from a in db.Dates
                     from b in db.Facts

                     where a.Count_Key == b.Date_key

                         select new{
                             a.Date1,
                           a.Month,
                         b.Fact_key
                         });
        var query2 = query.GroupBy(x =>  x.Month );
        Grid1.DataSource = query2;
        Grid1.DataBind();
```

So, when I try to bind with query it works perfectly, but query2 yields the error

> field date1 not found on selected datasource.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Of the date1 not found beacuse you are group by Month try to group by both fields

Comment: No. It still returns the same error

Answer (score 0):

Because you grouped by month, now you have only month field as a key, and collection of grouped items. If you want more fields on data source you need to use aggregate function on date1 field.

For example like this:

```
var query2 = (from q in query
             group q by q.Month into g
             select new 
                       {
                          Month = g.Key,
                          Date = g.Select(gg=>gg.Date1).Max //or you can use first here etc.
                       }).ToList()
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hey how can you access query2 even before it is declared

Answer (score 0):

The group by returns columns with different names than the original select.

You can do the following to see it "for educational purpose".

create a new Grid2 and use it with automatic columnmapping. Bind Query2 to this Grid2 and you will see the result.

Comment: Grid2.DataSource = query2 gives that error? In that case your Grid still has columndefinitions. You should do this with an empty, default grid and it cannot give that same error.

Comment: "The data source for GridView with id 'Grid2' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content." is the error i get even tough i say autogenerate columns="true

Comment: and when you debug, is your query(not query2) reference has data in it? sounds to me that your first query isn't right

Comment: It has data... query works perfectly when i bind it with query2 as source, then i get the error